# Read data from an electronic identity card using the USB reader on the client-side

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

We are developing a C# MVC app for technical inspection of the car and we have to read data from an electronic identity card and a registration certificate using the USB reader. During we developed the app we tested and ran it on a local computer and everything was working fine. Then we used a USB reader on our computer. Later, when we ran the application on the server and wanted to read data from another computer, our web application could not read data from another computer from the USB reader. We use two C++ DLL libraries to reading data from the Identity card and Registration certificate.
I think we have a problem why our application can't read data from another computer because these two DLLs are on the server, but we don't have that DLL on the client-side. I'm not sure how our web app can read card data when we use USB readers on another computer. Has anyone had a similar situation? I would like some advice. Thanks.

Comment: *In local everything is fine, but when we put our app on the server we can't read data.* -- then can you please edit your question to share a [mcve] -- a minimal set of code that reproduces the problem?  As it is we can only guess where you are going wrong.  See [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem... Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*.  You're more likely to be happy with the help you get here if you follow the advice at that link, as well as https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/.

Comment: But possibly related: [How to authenticate with certificates instead of passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31992827/344280) and [How can i access to smartcard from ASP.NET site?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3006629/344280), [Sign data using smart card's private key with ASP.NET, Windows Authentication, and Impersonation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16152210/344280).  These questions are all old though; the state of the art has likely moved on.  Details of your current code would help determine whether these answers apply.

Comment: The reader is on the client and you are trying to read the device on the server.  You have a webpage which is on the browser on the client.  So make sure you are looking for the USB device on the client and not the server.